# SpringBoot 2.5.2 and unit tests

Tags: junit4

My unit tests work inside Eclipse (Run with Junit Test) when my pom.xml is setup to use SpringBoot 2.3.12.RELEASE. When I try to use 2.5.2 they fail like this:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.computeAttribute

They work when you do a Maven build inside or outside Eclipse.

Anybody else having these kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy! It the things you overlook that get you. I had some project dependencies to other projects on my Eclipse project that I had not upgraded yet. As soon as I upgraded everything, all my unit tests started to run. My apologies.

Bob